# Prevent highlighting of keywords in strings starting with square brackets

Tags: listings, highlighting

I have the following MWE in pdfLaTeX.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{
    language=SQL,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    belowskip=3mm,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    breaklines=true,
    classoffset=0,
    columns=flexible,
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    framexleftmargin=0.25em,
    frameshape={}{}{}{},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    tabsize=3,
    upquote=true,
    xleftmargin=1em
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT e.[column] [Number example],
FROM Example e;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following.

[image: Current state]

However, I would like something more aligned to the highlighting from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which looks like this.

[image: Highlighting in Studio]

As you can see the type `Number` is not highlighted in the previous image. When the same is re-written for Oracle, it also looks acceptable. I would also accept answers that would make the `[Number example]` purple.

[image: Highlighting using Oracle syntax]

I tried looking for an answer on the web but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following turns `[...]` into a string with color `black` using the `morestring` key (if you remove the `[\color{black}]` you'll get the mauve/purple output you described as "also accept"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{
    language=SQL,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    belowskip=3mm,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    breaklines=true,
    classoffset=0,
    columns=flexible,
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    framexleftmargin=0.25em,
    frameshape={}{}{}{},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    tabsize=3,
    upquote=true,
    xleftmargin=1em
    ,morestring=[s][\color{black}]{[}{]}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT e.[column] [Number example],
FROM Example e;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]